# MonoTouch UIImage.FromFile not loading retina assets

Tags: ios, ios7, xamarin.ios, xamarin

I am testing in the simulator with iOS7. All my assets are retina only with the @2x name. I have a very weird behaviour with UIImage.FromFile.
Please note that the behaviour is the same with simulator iPad and simulator iPad Retina.

Basically:

- UIImage.FromBundle("Images/close.png"), this will work: it loads the close@2x.png and scales it down
- UIImage.FromFile("Images/close.png"), this doesn't work
- UIImage.FromFile("Images/close@2x.png"), this loads the image but i'm not sure it will do the expected things (ie: downscale it on non retina device and use it correctly on retina device)

Any hint? I thought that iOS7 was handling this automatically.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to the Xamarin documentation - [Working with Images](http://docs.xamarin.com/guides/ios/application_fundamentals/working_with_images/) (look in the end of the article) - `Using FromFile is similar to using FromBundle, except that you have to pass the entire file path, including file suffix.`, so it means that if you are using `FromFile` you should add `@2x` suffix to the end.

Comment: From my tests the entire filepath isn't necessary. Also from this discussion, @2x shouldn't be necessary: http://monotouch.2284126.n4.nabble.com/UIImage-FromFile-and-2x-images-td4655758.html

Comment: And this is some kind of bug (and it's discussed in that discussion) and what if xamarin team will fix it on the next build? Then if you not add the suffix it will work incorrect and you may not notice it, so it will be better to do all according to the documentation as you can not be sure that it will work in the same way after xamarin updates

Comment: You make a point. What is strange though is that when you look, using "Go to declaration", at the implementation of "FromFile" and "FromBundle" it seems to be doing the same thing.