# UIBarButtonItem displaying image on iPhone but not iPad

Tags: ios, xamarin.ios

I have seen a few questions around images displaying differently between Device and Simulator. This is **not** that. The image displays on an iPhone6 device but not on an iPad Air device. If I change from Image to simple text the button displays on both.

I add the button like this:

```
UIBarButtonItem searchButton = 
                      new UIBarButtonItem(
                                         UIImage.FromFile("Search-22"),           
                                            UIBarButtonItemStyle.Plain, null);

this.NavigationItem.SetRightBarButtonItem(searchButton, false);
```

How can I get this to display an image on both?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was in the call to FromFile rather than FromBundle. Once I switched to FromBundle I was able to use see the image in my Button.

```
UIImage searchImage = UIImage.FromBundle("Search-22.png");UIImage searchImage = UIImage.FromBundle("Search-22.png");
```

I got the final solution from this SO Q&A, [MonoTouch UIImage.FromFile not loading retina assets](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23102276/monotouch-uiimage-fromfile-not-loading-retina-assets)

The image on the iPad Mini does look a bit jagged so I may have other issues

Answer (score 1):

I've experienced this before too.

Firstly you need the extension, there are some subtle differences between the platforms iPad / iPhone.

Personally to debug, I would break it down:

```
var searchImage = UIImage.FromFile("Search-22.png");
UIBarButtonItem searchButton = new UIBarButtonItem(searchImage, UIBarButtonItemStyle.Plain, null);

this.NavigationItem.SetRightBarButtonItem(searchButton, false);
```

Then you can debug each line, and check if the `searchImage` object is null or not.

Obvious as well, check your naming conventions:

- MyImage@2x.png [Universal]
- MyImage@2x~iphone.png [iPhone only]
- MyImage@2x~ipad.png [iPad only]

Comment: The design team gave me 2 images Search-22@2x.png and Search-22@3x.png. Is that wrong?

Comment: No that's correct. "@2x" is for Retina, and "@3x" is for Retina+ (the newer iPhone 6 and iPhone 6+ models). You can place these images directly in the resources folder, or add them to an image assets container. The device will automatically know which one to pick. You simply reference "Search-22.png"

Comment: Thanks for the debugging advice. Once I split it into separate line it was easier to  search for the issue.